# EPPlus namedstyle horizontalAlignment

Tags: alignment, epplus

I have problem implementing the following code:

```
var newNamedStyle=_workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("testStyle");     
newNamedStyle.Style.HorizontalAlignment=ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center; 
newNamedStyle.Style.Font.Size=15;
```

but EPPlus doesn't seem to be able to capture the Horizontal Alignment properly.

Could this be a bug with EPPlus?

Any work around for that?

Answer (score 12):

I was able to horizontally center a cell with EPPlus (3.1.3) like this.

```
 xlWorkSheet.Cells["A1"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Maybe you should also point out more explicitly that it needs to be set on a cell range, not on the entire workbook as jxnim was trying to do.